# Integration Tests for RESTEasy Endpoint

Tags: rest, integration-testing, resteasy

I want to perform integration tests on my REST endpoint but am running into issues.

Below is my endpoint. NOTE: I cannot change this part of the code.

```
@Path("/people")
public class PersonResource {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Inject
    public PersonResource(final PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personService.getPersonList();
    }
}
```

From what I've been able to find online, I have the following basic structure for my test.

```
public class PersonResourceTest {

    private Dispatcher dispatcher;
    private POJOResourceFactory factory;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        factory = new POJOResourceFactory(PersonResource.class);
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(factory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEndpoint() throws URISyntaxException {
        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("people");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n" + response.getStatus() + "\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n" + response.getContentAsString() + "\n\n\n\n\n");
    }

}
```

However, this results in the following error on the last line of the `setup` method.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: my.path.PersonResource
```

I explored the `Registry` API and thought maybe I should have been using `addSingletonResource` instead, so I changed the last line of `setup` to `dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(personResource);` and added the following.

```
@Inject
private PersonResource personResource;
```

But that results in a `NullPointerException` on the last line of `setup`.

The [sparse documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Server-side_Mock_Framework.html) on the mocking isn't very helpful. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things

1. Add a no arguments constructor to your source class:

```
    public PersonResource() {
        this(null)
    }
```

2. In the test class, initialize the PersonResource class with an instance of PersonService class:

```
    dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new PersonResource(new PersonService()));
```

If needed, the PersonService class can be mocked:

```
private Dispatcher dispatcher;

@Mock
private PersonService service;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
    PersonResource resource= new PersonResource(service);
    ispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(resource);
}
```

Hope it helps!